# OpenGLRenderer trying to scale down bitmap - when reaching end of ViewPager

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-viewpager, android-bitmap

App has a `ViewPager` with several `Fragment` in it.

When user scrolls to the end of pages, there's this Android gradient effect that indicates there's no more pages (instead of iOS's bounce effect).

When this effect occurs, apps become unresponsive and frames are dropped, while in the log there these lines -

```
Trying to scale down bitmap for texture (2560x4544 -> 2307x4096)
Scaled bitmap has been successfully created
```

There's no bitmap in the app of this size and it's running on a QHD (1440 x 2560 pixels) LG G3 display, so I guess some bitmap is scaled up to fit this xxxhdpi resolution, then for some reason scaled down a bit.

Question is - why is it trying to scale down a bitmap when this effect occurs? Can this be avoided?

Is it the gradient effect rendering that is being scaled down?

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Yes, maybe not the perfect solution, but it was good enough for me. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stopped when I turned off the over scroll effect (iOS's bounce equivalent). Maybe this effect is an image that's resized before shown, though I don't understand why they don't cache it, if it's true.

```
viewPager.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with loading some image in your page:
Solutions:
1. if you must load the image use a library named Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/ to load it
2. if the image is a shape try to make the shape yourself in android.
At all costs avoid loading big images in the xml. even in the newest phones this has a big impact on performance.